# How can I get an SFTP server running on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp

I have a remote Windows 2008 machine and the task at hand is to share out parts of its filesystem via SFTP for a single user.

Were commercial software an option things would be easy but I want freeware.

After trying out several different candidates such as [Core FTP Mini SFTP Server](http://coreftp.com/server/index.html), [SilverShield](http://www.k2sxs.com/silvershield/) and [freeFTPd](http://www.freesshd.com/) none them really qualified - either connection issues, zero configurability or bugs.

**Is there a free and stable SFTP server for Windows 2008 which works out of the box?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option would be to [install OpenSSH using Cygwin](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188155/Installing-an-SSH-SFTP-Server-on-Windows). The attached instructions are for Windows XP/Vista but I don't see why they wouldn't work on Windows Server 2008.

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a kind of middle layer that allows *nix software to be compiled and run on Windows without modification. It is extremely handy and brings a lot of other *nix goodness to Windows. Oh, yeah and Cygwin is open source and free.

Comment: Cygwin gives only source compatibility, not binary compatibility - I made an edit suggestion to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

After spending a few hours on the World Wide Web, turns out the answer is **yes**.

Meet [KpyM Telnet/SSH Server](http://www.kpym.com/2/kpym/index.htm) which is a free, open source telnet/ssh server for Windows.

Installation is a breeze and it runs as a service.

The only caveat is the requirement to grant explicit access rights to SFTP home folder - KpyM authentication relies on Windows user accounts.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/)  ? We have been using this for our server and it does the job for us. It is free and easy to setup.

The download page is here http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=download

After you install it, check in your taskbar, the application should be running and the icon is  hidden in the taskbar next to the clock.

Comment: It is worth noting that this server has a GUI for configuring the settings whereas the KpyM server only provides a command line interface (as far as I could tell).

Answer (score 0):

This is a free SFTP server which runs on Windows 2008 and is free for private use, or trial:

http://windsftp.weebly.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Syncplify.me Server!](http://www.syncplify.me/products/server/) as well. It's free for non commercial use, and your single user scenario fits the free license technical limitations.

And unlike Cygwin/OpenSSH solutions this one is Windows-native, as per your request.